# Google Maps API find My Location on Load Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I have got a Google Maps and Places API via javascript code.
When the page loads it will automatically go to the Latitude defined in the code.  Is there a way to have it AUTOMATICALLY go to where it thinks your location is, without having a button or search field?

Using this code currently:

```
google.maps.LatLng(37.783259, -122.402708);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(google.loader.ClientLocation)
    {
visitor_lat = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude;
      visitor_lon = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude;
};

new google.maps.LatLng(visitor_lat, visitor_lon);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `sensor=true` when calling the API?

[Source](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#DetectingUserLocation)